# SmoothDensityHistogram - Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram

I made Monte Carlo simulation of a cone shaped light source - like lighthouse. Then I tried to draw results. I took the points from which the rays have come. Then I tried to draw SmoothDensityHistogram, but I have problems with binning. I know that the most rays came from {0,0,0}, but that is just not obvious from the picture. The center is somehow translated, but it should't be.
Here's a link to [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pDMaS9TDltV2J5V2xpWkEyZmc/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post some code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your picture doesn't have public access, at least it is not accessible for me.

Comment: I think you should be able to access image now. I solved this problem using BinCounts and than I manually selected bins belonging to certain points. I plotted the results using ListDensityPLot. I couldn't get SmoothDensityPlot to make centered image.

Comment: @Jur I still don't know where the problem is. "Monte Carlo simulation of light source" - like in photon-tracing? "cone shaped" - is this relevant? Then which shape, can you sketch it or define it? Is it the surface of light source, or a reflector? "like lighthouse" - the light source, or the name of a software or algorithm? "draw results" - What is your desired result, photon hits on a surface? "points from which the rays" - which rays? points on the surface of the lightsource, mirror, something else? Or is the question simply on SmoothDensityHistogram regardless of where the points come?

Comment: I just wanted to sketch the background a bit - the part about monte carlo,.. is not really important. Essentially, it's a binning problem. Mathematica won't make bin centered at (0,0). It will make one bin centered for example at (0,0.1) one at (0,-0.1), (0.1,0) and (-0.1,0). The problem is that a lot of points are (0,0) and Matheamtica bins them all into one of those four bins, which is wrong.

Comment: 1D example: Lets say you have points on interval [-10,10]  and you have lots of zeros. Those zeros will be binned to either (0,epsilon) or  (-epsilon,0). But I am not happy with this. I want Mathematica to make a bin on interval (-epsilon/2, epsilon/2).

Comment: I see. Could you please post the value array of which you did the SmoothDensityPlot? Otherwise it is hard to reproduce the result.

Answer (score -1):

try to play with the PlotPoints option. Even value of the parameter could help, even though I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
tb = Table[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3]], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3]]}, {n, 10000}];
SmoothDensityHistogram[tb, PlotPoints -> 6]
```